# In the update action a NoMethodError is thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionpack

This is my source code

```
 def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
        format.html {redirect_to :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

I get an error on this line

```
respond_to do |format|
```

and the error message is "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it. The error occurred while evaluating nil.call".

The five lines from the stack trace are as follows

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:175:in `respond'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:173:in `respond'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.4/lib/action_controller/mime_responds.rb:107:in `respond_to'
/Path from my machine to the app/app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:43:in `update'
```

I have no idea on how to debug this and I cannot understand how can this error be raised.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't responding to non-html clients, you don't have to use the respond_to.

Try changing the method to:

```
  if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
   redirect_to :action => "edit"
  end
```

If that works, the error looks like it is somewhere in the mime type configuration of your app.

Comment: Thanks Toby. It helped, now I have to check my mime type configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This cryptic error appears when you don't use the yieled *format* object. In fact, you really should do something when the update_attributes call fails, for example rendering the *edit* template:

```
  def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
        format.html { redirect_to [:edit, @recipe] }
      else 
        format.html { render :template => 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```